# Finding the extrema of function without differentiating

Tags: calculus

I have a function $f(x,y) = x^2 - 4xy +3y^2$ . How can one discuss its extrema without differentiating the function ? A little hint ...may be we find the hassian matrix and check but we are asked to find them without differentiating ?

Comment: Try completing the square.

Answer (score 11):

An idea might be to look at 
$f(x,y)=x^2-4xy+3y^2=(x-2y)^2-y^2=(x-3y)(x-y)$

and observe the roots of this function.

Remember that the vertex of the x-coordinate of a quadratic function is at the middle of the two roots.

Comment: What do the roots of a function tell us about its extrema ?

Comment: For example, the roots are $x=3y$ and $x=y$. So, we expect the minima to be at $x=(3y+y)/2=2y$, which we can confirm by taking the derivative.